# YouTube copyright

Tags: видео, youtube, авторские-права

Я снимаю ботов для одной мобильной игры и выкладываю ролик на ютуб. Разработчики подают заявку на нарушение авторских прав из-за ботов для их игры. Что можно сделать в ролике, чтобы ютуб не забанил за нарушение авторских прав игры?

Comment: Вообще снимать контент по игре не является нарушением. Возможно, создание ботов не попадает под эту категорию (хотя должно...)

Comment: Чтобы я не снял про эту мобильную игру, разработчики всегда могут подать заявку на нарушение АП. Но они этого не делают просто так, а только если что-то запрещённое в их игре (бот)

Comment: А разве создавать ботов запрещено? Или это написано в пользовательском соглашении? Если написано, то чего вы ещё хотели

Comment: По правилам игры - запрещено. Но как я могу на ютубе избежать нарушение АП? Чтобы разработчики не смогли доказать, что это их игра

Comment: Можете наложить эффекты (цветовой фильтр и т.д., но это врятли поможет), попробовать создать свою игру по типу этой, но с изменённым геймплеем, но лучше либо отказаться от этого, либо пробовать на другой видео-площадке

Comment: Также можно не упоминать и не показывать для какой игры бот (только  его создание). Но тогда люди скорее всего не поймут...

Comment: А если в названии ролика есть название игры, это нарушение АП?

Comment: Вообще - нет. Вы же сами видели сколько роликов на YouTube с названиями игр. Да и если создание ботов запрещено правилами игры (вроде не читерить, не багоюзить) - вас тоже не должны блокировать (ролики о игре с читами далеко не всегда блокируются). Если в пользовательском соглашении - это другое дело. Соглашение вы приняли, значит не должны нарушать. Также можете почитать: http://7youtube.ru/others-on-youtube/oboyti-avtorskie-pravana.html